# Make Windows 7 Login Screen look like the Windows XP login screen

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, login-screen

Is there a way to make the login screen in Windows 7 look like the one in Windows XP, i.e boxes for:

- Username
- Password
- Domain

I know this is a bit of a strange one, and trust me, I wouldn't do it if I didn't have to. Even if there was just a way to select the domain from a dropdown box would be good. We are trying to have non domain users login to the local machine instead of onto the domain with a generic username and password.

For future reference I found that the easiest way to solve the problem I was having (Getting local users to log on easily) is to add a ./ in front of the username.
i.e **./joebloggs**

Comment: +1, the windows vista/7 "switch user" workflow is _painful_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the guy behind Paralint.com, pointed out by lsxek. I'm working on the back end, and my work will not help you bring back the XP look, sorry.

Getting credentials from a user is handled by a Credential Provider. There are samples in the [lastest Platform SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx). If you choose to go down that path, you will end up doing this:

1. Build a Credential Provider that informs LogonUI.exe of the field you need
2. Fill those fields with data, like a list of domains
3. When notified that you tile was filled out, serialize the credentials for LSASS.exe to handle

If it is just a matter of rearranging the look of the logon screen, Microsoft's samples will give you a good head start. But I would - and I'm sure you have by now - consider the benefits you will get out of that work, considering maintenance and all...

Answer (score 7):

According to [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprosecurity/thread/17ff1429-9d3b-4322-96d2-950a6ae12230), it's not possible because both Windows Vista and 7 does not use the old MSGina.DLL file that provided the said dialog box. However, there's a suggested registry edit in the same thread that would allow you to hide accounts you do not wish to display at the logon screen.

**EDIT:** Apparently I didn't do a complete search. There's an opensource project called [pGina](http://www.pgina.org/) which might help here. It requires .NET Framework v3.5 SP1, and it has an LDAP authorization-related plugin. However, support for Windows 7 is still pretty much a work in progress.

**EDIT 2:** Another possible solution in the works: someone is [porting their custom GINA to a Credential provider](http://www.paralint.com/blog/2009/02/24/porting-a-custom-gina-to-a-credential-provider/) suitable for use in Vista (and possibly Windows 7).

Comment: I'm going to hold out for a few more days. If not I think this is a good an answer as I'm going to get.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/01/28/revert-and-change-to-xp-classic-logon-screen-on-windows-7-or-vista/

Comment: Doesn't display the domain unfortunately.